# Merging files based on common fields

Tags: join, csv

I'm trying to join three text files in similar formats based on common fields, while keeping the uncommon fields. Here's an example:

File1:

```
  X
A 1
B 3
C 2
D 1
```

File2:

```
  Y
A 3
C 2
E 3
```

File3:

```
  Z
A 2
E 1
D 1
F 3
```

Merged:

```
  X Y Z
A 1 3 2
B 3 - -
C 2 2 -
D 1 - 1
E - 3 1
F - - 3
```

It doesn't have to be a *-* where there's no corresponding value. The join command in this question https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43417/join-two-files-with-matching-columns works well except that it doesn't keep the uncommon fields.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`join` can't do what you're asking for, but here's a Python program that does:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python                                                                                                   

import sys

files = map(open, sys.argv[1:]) # list of input files

headers = map(file.readline, files) # list of strings
headers = map(str.strip, headers)

blanks = ['-'] * len(headers)
data = {} # { rowname : [datum...] }                                                                   

for ii, infile in enumerate(files): # read each file
        for line in infile:
                key, value = line.split()
                if key not in data:
                        data[key] = blanks[:] # deep copy
                data[key][ii] = value

print '\t', '\t'.join(headers)

for key, values in sorted(data.iteritems()):
        print key, '\t', '\t'.join(values)
```

Comment: It worked perfectly! Exactly what I wanted. Thanks bro.